# Time series analysis in R (figuring out trends)

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-models, mixed

I have a dataset of tweets from 2013 to 2017. I have coded for certain message features(coded 0 as absence and 1 as presence), and was trying to figure out if there is a trend (i.e., the occurrence of message feature going up/down gradually) in my dataset. How should I do it in R?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You could try a linear model, such as one of the answer given in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197084/binary-time-series).

```
#for reproducing
set.seed(200)
library(ggplot2)
#simple example. Assume your data is simple binomial variable with probability 0.3
data <- data.frame(time = 1:200, val=sample(c(0,1), size = 200, replace = T, prob = c(0.3, 0.7)))

#plot using ggplot and add linear regression and confidence interval
ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y=val)) + geom_smooth(method=lm) +geom_point()

#Now we can try to create linear regression
y = data$time
    x = data$val
fitData <- lm(x ~ y)
predict(fitData, newdata = data.frame(y=201:224), interval="confidence")

#You can also take advantage of geom_smooth that find the best model if your don't specify any:
ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y=val)) + geom_smooth() +geom_point()

#Here, it seems that loess would be better
```

Some code to do a loess regression in R [here](http://r-statistics.co/Loess-Regression-With-R.html).

Good luck!